# New agressive delete policy completely demotivates answering

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

It is just now that I tried to answer [this beginner question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834304/swi-prolog-gives-too-many-solutions). I gave a short reply first to ensure that the question will not be deleted while I am writing an answer, as it has happened so frequently in the past. Even today, I had such a case - a program containing the rather unique textstrings `a4`, `kostas`, `maria`, `nikos` in case you want to check it out. However, while completing my answer the question was deleted. So again I wasted my time on SO for nothing.

For low-frequency tags like this one ([prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog)), there is definitely no longer any good reason to answer beginner's questions, even if they do permit to show some unique debugging techniques and therefore would contribute to the content of SO.

What is rationale behind this new policy?

Edit: According to below comments, the question and user had been deleted.  Nevertheless the messages that I received did not indicate this.

Comment: That question wasn't down voted or close voted by the community at all. I also only see 9 deleted questions among the last 50 Prolog questions asked. That seems about normal (as compared to recent Java and C# questions).  This doesn't seem to be a policy issue.

Answer (score 27):

The one question that you provided was not deleted by a moderator or the community.  It was deleted by the user that posted the question.

If you are answering questions that *are* being deleted by moderators, the community, or automatic deletion criteria then the *goal* is to discourage you from answering those *very* low quality questions.  We *don't* want you answering questions that don't belong on the site, and that fall well below the minimum standards of quality.  When you answer these questions you encourage people to continue to ask them, and then that means *more* low quality content that we need to try to get rid of.

You should be spending your time answering *quality* questions that *do* meet the site's guidelines.  It's a *good thing* for you to take a short moment to evaluate a given question and ensure that it meets the site's guidelines before beginning to answer it.

I'd also like to note that it is not "beginner" questions or "easy" questions that are a problem.  Good questions are questions that are clear, on topic, appropriately scoped, can be objectively answered, have enough information to be answered, are understandable, are well researched, etc.  While it is true that many people who ask basic programming questions also haven't developed the skills of how to ask good questions, meeting these criteria, there are plenty of people who ask simple, easy, basic questions, but do so while meeting all of these criteria.  These questions are fine.  Conversely, some experienced developers ask very complex and difficult questions, but also don't meet the given criteria.  Those questions are just as problematic.

When a given question doesn't meet the site's guidelines first focus on *fixing the question by helping the author clarify what they mean, add missing information, improve the grammar/spelling/formatting, include research, etc.  Once the question has been improved *then* you can answer it.  This is *far* more likely to result in high quality answers, which is the goal of the site.

Comment: Both questions definitely do belong to the site.

Comment: "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation" - doesn't that mean [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834304/swi-prolog-gives-too-many-solutions) _was_ deleted by a moderator?

Comment: @halfer that's just a general message that says nothing specific.

Comment: @halfer It looks like that user's account was deleted, either because of highly abusive behavior (account deletion, rather than suspension, is mostly just for spammers, which this doesn't seem to be) on their end, or more likely, because they requested deletion.

Comment: @AD7six Yes, the account is deleted.

Comment: I suppose account deletion is the reason for "deleted for moderation reasons" instead of "deleted by its author" @ChrisF

Comment: @Servy - They deleted their own account, in this case, and deleted their question on the way out. Odd how we tend to see a lot of that this time of year. Almost like something's coming to the end of a term.

Comment: @brasofilo indeed. SE is very particular about not giving out too much information in cases like this.

Comment: @BradLarson Weird, man. It's almost like they don't want other people to find the answer to the *exact same question* for some reason.

Comment: @BradLarson Meh, to be fair, the comment on the answer indicates that it was an unrelated environmental problem, indicating that the question isn't actually answerable as it stands and wouldn't be useful to anyone else, so deleting it really isn't a problem.  Unless that comment was a lie, in which case, it seems unnecessarily elaborate.

Comment: As a general rule we don't let people delete their content on the way out the door, right? So someone who knows the domain should figure if this question call for un-deletion.

Comment: @dmckee For the reasons I described in my previous comment, this question *doesn't* seem like it merits undeletion.

Comment: @Servy: I do not agree with your qualification of the question: It was an opportunity to illustrate some Prolog-specific debugging strategies.

Comment: @false And yet it's not an answer to the question.  It's information that's tangential to the question itself.  It may be useful, but because it's not related to the actual question it's not *discoverable*, so people having problems that would be helped by your answer aren't going to find your answer.

Comment: Content is only saved if the community finds that content valuable enough to upvote it.  No upvotes, no reason for it to stick around.  The deleted post didn't have any upvotes on either the question or the answer.

Comment: @Servy: Do you want to go that far as to include into an answer excusilvely what is discoverable via the question?? That would reduce Prolog-specific beginner questions to practically zero.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Deletion occurred while I was completing my answer which was some minutes after posing the question.

Comment: @false No, and I never claimed that.  An answer can include some useful tangential information *in addition to* answering the question (although keeping it to a reasonable amount *is* important), but not *instead of* answering the question.

Comment: @false I bet the OP saw your answer. Copied pasted it somewhere and then deleted the question and the account to "cover his tracks".

Comment: @Mysticial That doesn't appear to be the case.  Read his comment on the post.  He answered his own question, and it was because of an environmental issue unrelated to the information in the question, rendering the question moot, so he deleted it.  That was entirely appropriate of him.  If he didn't delete it it ought to have been closed as "cannot reproduce the issue".

Comment: @Servy Ah. I missed that. Then I eat my words. Nevertheless, that type user is pretty common. And possibly one of the more poisonous types of help vampires that we see.

Comment: @Mysticial: I started with a first answer, and then added TBC and saved it, then I continued to add more detail which then, while writing turned out to be unsaveable...

Answer (score 7):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834304/swi-prolog-gives-too-many-solutions) you link to was not deleted as a matter of policy, it was deleted by its author. Normally, you would see a different message when browsing in that case (“voluntarily removed by its author”). The message for this question is “removed (…) for reasons of moderation” because the account that posted the question is also deleted and the database record thus no longer relates the deleter to the poster.

The general rules for deleting one's own question are:

- If there are valuable answers, then deleting the question is not allowed, because it would also delete the answers and we don't give the asker such power.
- If there are no valuable answers, then the asker is allowed to retract their question.

When there are answers, the software cannot determine whether they are valuable. The approximation that is implemented is: if there are multiple answers, or if there is an answer with a positive score, then the answers are considered valuable; if there is an answer with a nonpositive score, it is not considered valuable. Your answer fell in an unfortunate case where the approximation is incorrect.

There is a comment on the question:

> Yes, that is intended. The problem is now solved because I switched from the Prolog editor (which didn't work) to the ordinary swi-Prolog and now I only get one solution as it was supposed to be. But I don't anderstand what you mean with "here is term_variables/2 as an ISO built-in predicate" ?

It's possible that the author deleted their question because switching compilers was good enough for them and they didn't care about the rest. If you feel that the question and your answer are valuable nonetheless, you can request to have them undeleted. I'm not a Prolog expert, but to me this looks like a very specific code critique which isn't of general interest and doesn't warrant undeletion.

Comment: There were several issues of general interest